# Print array values(json formatted) on web page in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, web

I have the following function on my .html page:

```
function Success(data)
{
var obj;
obj=JSON.parse(data);
document.write(obj);
}
```

that returns the objects as **Hi,Hello,How,Are,You,Me,They,Them**
I would like to achieve the following : [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VApCb.png)

How do I do this?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. Take a look at [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `obj` is a string then you can split it's content by ',' and generate a table as follows:

```js
var obj;
obj=JSON.parse(data);
obj = obj.split(',')

result = '<table><tr>';
obj.forEach(function (item, i) {
  result += '<td>' + item +'</td>';
  if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) result += '</tr><tr>';
})
result += '</tr></table>';

document.write(result);
```

you will probably need to style the table after.